# Why does using a character class make this left-recursive?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have the following to define a basic arithmetic grammar:

```
grammar Calc;


expression
    : '(' expression ')'                // parenExpression has highest precedence
    | expression ('*' | '/') expression // then multDivExpression
    | expression ('+' | '-') expression // then addSubExpression
    | OPERAND
    ;

// 12 or .12 or 2. or 2.38
OPERAND
    : [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]*)?
    | '.' [0-9]+
    ;
```

And it can handle something like:

```
1+2*3
```

However, as soon as I change the `('*' | '/')` to the character class `[*/]` I get the following error:

[image]

How does adding a character class do this? Or is it because I'm trying to add that to a parser rule and not a lexer rule, or why does that occur?

**Update**: extracting the character class out of the grammar rule fixes it, but it'd be great to understand why:

```
expression
    : '(' expression ')'           // parenExpression has highest precedence
    | expression MULDIV expression // then multDivExpression
    | expression ADDSUB expression // then addSubExpression
    | OPERAND
    ;

MULDIV
    : [*/]
    ;

ADDSUB
    : [-+]
    ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character classes are only available to Lexer rules.

when you put literals (`'+'`, `'/'`, etc.) implicit Lexer rules are defined for you (and given rather unusable names like `T__1`, `T__2`, etc.). So they're just convenient ways of inserting implicit tokens.  (The character class is only available in actual Lexer rules.)

Not sure which version of ANTLR you're using, but I get a "rule expression has no defined parameters" error, and not mutual left recursion.

I think you're seeing a side effect of the character class syntax not being available in parser rules.  (The `[`...`]` syntax has an entirely different meaning in parser rules.)

Comment: thanks again for all your help. Regarding -- `The [...] syntax has an entirely different meaning in parser rules` -- what is its meaning in parser rules?

Comment: rules can accept arguments, and this syntax allows you to pass those arguments to the attempt to match the rule.  Honestly, I've not used them, so I'd have to look up an example of where it might be used.